# Winterbash 2013?

Tags: discussion

The deadline for the winterbash is looming on Dec. 1 and there haven't been any announcements here yet, so here goes.

---

Hats have are new and redesigned for this year's [winterbash](http://winterba.sh/)! It will last from Dec. 16, 2013 to Jan. 3, 2014 if we decide to opt in. 
If you weren't around last year for the winterbash, here's how it works.

> Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard

If anyone hates hats and festivity, there will be a <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button they can click on and they will all disappear.

[image]

---

*Winterbash is on an opt-in basis.* If the we want to join, we need to let the mods know so they can let the community team know. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we took a unilateral view and opted us in this week. The official announcement from SE will come out in the first week in December, so prepare yourself for

**HATS!**

Answer (score 5):

## Hats are awesome!!!!

*Vote this up if you want hats.*

[image]

Comment: Is that a doorknob? That looks like a doorknob.