# Are we doing hats this December?

Tags: feature-request

Are we having ***HATS*** this year?

We did [**last year**](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/610/winterbash-2013/611).

## Hats are cool.

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes [@MatthewRead opted us in for it.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18725823#18725823)

It's going to go on from December 15th to January 4th.